# Filesystem created and last accessed times

Tags: file-system

Why doesn't Android keep track of the created and last accessed times as well as the last modified time for files in the file-system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't store creation time because UNIX filesystems (generally speaking) simply don't store this anywhere, and Android doesn't seem to be any different. [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408272/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-linux) has some discussion about this fact (you can ignore the fact that it's talking about Python - the answers are still relevant), and the man page for [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) describes what times are typically stored in the data structure.

As for the last accessed times...well it *does* keep track. Try `ls -l` in any directory you have proper permissions for:

```
$ cd /sdcard/
cd /sdcard/
$ ls -l
ls -l
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2011-04-27 14:31 LOST.DIR
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2011-04-27 14:31 DCIM
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2011-04-27 14:31 Android
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2011-04-27 16:14 glogs
-rwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw    49152 2011-05-27 16:04 AndroidBytes.txt
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2011-06-28 16:28 vim
-rwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw        0 2011-09-11 16:48 su-2.3.1-bin-signed.zip
$
```

If you have `busybox` you can also use the `stat` command for more detailed info. It also lets you use some additional `ls` flags like `-u`, `-c` and `-t` (see [`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) if you're not familiar with it). Here's a sample from `stat`:

```
# stat databases
stat databases
  File: "databases"
  Size: 2048            Blocks: 4          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 1f06h/7942d     Inode: 454         Links: 1
Access: (0771/drwxrwx--x)  Uid: (10079/  app_79)   Gid: (10079/  app_79)
Access: 2011-09-29 09:07:44.000000000
Modify: 2011-09-29 09:07:44.000000000
Change: 2011-09-29 09:07:44.000000000
#
```

Comment: When using stat on a file on the sdcard one gets 'Uid: (0/root)' .

Comment: *"It doesn't store creation time because UNIX filesystems (generally speaking) simply don't store this anywhere"* -- what??? UNIX systems DO store creation time! You can access them with the `-c` option to `ls`.